# How do I use a tracer with Auto Configuration?

Tags: distributed-tracing, open-telemetry-java

I am following the tutorial [Manual instrumentation for OpenTelemetry Java](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/manual), trying to make Auto Configuration to work. After a few tries I managed to see the metrics sent to an OTel Collector.

Unfortunately I am not able to see the traces.

I tried to debug with VS Code and found out that a tracer doesn't get created because of this line of code

```
List<Integer> result = new Dice(1, 6).rollTheDice(rolls.get());
```

which should be instead

```
List<Integer> result = new Dice(1, 6, openTelemetry).rollTheDice(rolls.get());
```

This last one contains the initializazion of the tracer.

How should I modify the code in order to be able to pass the `openTelemetry` object? Only in the second case the tracer is invoked, but I am not able to provide the `openTelemetry` object from the method that contains `Dice()` (Springboot `index`.)